# Matrix product with for cycles

Tags: algorithm

Give the matrices:

```
A = {{a11, a12, a13, a14},
     {a21, a22, a23, a24},
     {a31, a32, a33, a34}};

B = {{b11, b12, b13},
     {b21, b22, b23},
     {b31, b32, b33}};
```

by calculating:

```
Transpose[A].B.A
```

it is clear that a 4x4 matrix is obtained whose first entry is:

```
a11 (a11 b11 + a21 b21 + a31 b31) + 
a21 (a11 b12 + a21 b22 + a31 b32) + 
a31 (a11 b13 + a21 b23 + a31 b33)
```

My goal is to write a series of nested *for cycles* to get the 4x4 entries of that matrix.

After many unsuccessful attempts I am here to ask if someone could give me a hand or show me some book where I could find this algorithm written.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't self vandalise your posts.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left. You may need to use a browser, not the mobile app.

Comment: Why would you vandalize your post when you got a helpful answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compute that purely with for loops the algorithm would be:

```
for i = 1..4
    for j = 1..4
        v := 0
        for p = 1..3
            t := 0
            for q = 1..3
                t := t + a[q, i] * b[q, p]
            v := v + a[p, j] * t
        c[i, j] := v
```

Where `c` is the 4x4 output matrix.

Here is a demonstration in Python:

```py
import numpy as np

# Make input matrices
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
b = np.arange(12, 21).reshape(3, 3)
# Compute result with matrix products
c = a.T @ b @ a
# Compute result with loops
c2 = np.empty([4, 4], dtype=a.dtype)
for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        v = 0
        for p in range(a.shape[0]):
            t = 0
            for q in range(a.shape[0]):
                t += a[q, i] * b[q, p]
            v += a[p, j] * t
        c2[i, j] = v
# Check result
print((c == c2).all())
# True
```